# How does Rails handle two dependent destroy clauses that are also dependent on each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :push_registrations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

There is a foreign_key constraint on the `push_registrations` table:

```
push_registrations_devices_fk" FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES devices(id)
```

If I were to call `user.destroy`, how does Rails attempt to destroy the `user`'s associated devices, when `user` still has an existing `PushRegistration` that references said `Device`?

Confused both on how Rails handles it as well as Postgres' point of view, thanks!

edit for more info:

```
class PushRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :client
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tokens
  has_many :push_registrations
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the foreign key constraint coming from on push registration?

So rails has a little bit of magic when you set up your relationships. The question is, how is your push registrations set up? If push_registrations is an object that belongs to device, then it should only reference the device. For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :devices, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :push_registrations, through: :devices
end

 class Devices < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :push_registrations, dependent: :destroy
end

 class PushRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :device
   has_one :user, through: :device
end
```

Rails magic will allow you to chain down the line with something like this

```
user.devices.each do |device|
   device.name
   device.push_registration.id
end
```

You don't need to set up a foreign key for user on your push registration table. With your belongs to, you can also chain back up the other way and go

```
push_registrations.each do |pr|
   pr.id
   pr.device
end
```

Hopefully that answers your question. If not let me know where I might've lost you!

Comment: I added the two model definitions to my original question to be clear. This is an existing project that has been running for a while, so reworking the associations and table schemas isn't an option right now.

Comment: My main question is how/when Rails fires off the deletions for the associations, and what happens given the fact one of it's associations has a fk constraint on the other. Like, I think I understand the call order, but not sure really how to work around the current setup. Do I have to add a dependent: :destroy on the push_registrations has_many :devices declaration?

Comment: And to answer your question, the fk constraint was explicitly added in a migration

Comment: Yes, give that a shot. Seems like a bit of a cluster since you have a 3 way situation going on...

Comment: Adding a dependent: :destroy to `Device` did fix it, but like you said, it's really more of bad data modeling, your has_many :through suggestion would have been the best way to go about it originally. But that was long ago, before me, so this will be a good fix for now. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer for you. Sorry you had to walk into that situation. I feel for ya.